# Ios synching text from server

Tags: ios, synchronization

I am a beginner ios developer.I am tryin to develop a simple jokes app.Is it possible to code this app so it connects to a server every time the user opens the app, and syncs the jokes list with the one the server.If yes,what softwares do i need  to set up the server and how do i make it interact with the app.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely possible.  From the ios side, the server implementation is irrelevant as long as there are GET or POST requests that will return the data you are interested in.  Prior to ios 5, you can use NSURLConnection and NSURLRequest to make the requests and handle the results.

I have yet to develop an app targeted for ios 5, so I am not sure of the other options there.

Your question's scope is a bit huge, so good luck.